# Issues presenting UIViewController in Xcode 11, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, qr-code, xcode11

I have a QR Code scanner, which is embedded in a UIViewController. I've been looking around at other posts and blogs but all are single page apps which present the UIViewController as the primary one on launch of the application. I just need it to open inside of a button action, and for some reason I can't get it to present the scanner correctly?

Here's the QR Scanner Code:

```
class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

and here's my (very simplistic) attempt to have it open upon pressing a button:

```
struct ScanView: View{
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                ScannerViewController()
            }) {
                Text("Scan QR Code").foregroundColor(Color.white).padding()
            }.frame(width: 150)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(25)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at a few other StackOverflow posts regarding these types of issues, but some are either using deprecated ways of scanning qr codes or are otherwise irrelevant to the issue I'm facing.

I'm sure it's something fairly simple but my Swift/Xcode expertise mostly regards design and styling with basic knowledge of API calls, but I don't necessarily understand how the different view hierarchies and calling methods work.

I would like to fix this issue, of course, but I'd also like to know what the issue was so that I can know for next time.

Comment: Have you ever tried to find out what `viewDidLoad` is for?

Comment: Now that you point that out not so discretely, I'll make sure to look into it. Even though that was a rhetorical question, I mine as well answer with what my current knowledge is so I can compare down the road; I was under the impression that viewDidLoad was something which runs post-overall view load (as in once contentview loads) so viewDidLoad in this case is useless, if not causing it to pull up the scanner before the button is actually pressed.

Comment: @ElTomato I'm having a lot of trouble finding out enough in the time since my last comment to resolve my issue, could you give me a resolved code sample so I can see where I went wrong? I understand why viewDidLoad isn't appropriate in this context, but I have no clue how to adjust my code to remove those referencing lines. Also just realized I posted this comment on an alternate account, we're the same person though.

Answer (score 1):

We can not directly call `UIViewController` in `SwiftUI`.
Need `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to present a `UIViewController`.

You can read about it here:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable
- https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Try this, it is working and I can see the content through camera :

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

struct ScannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ScannerViewController

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ScannerViewController, context: Context) {
        print("update")
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ScannerViewController {
        return ScannerViewController()
    }

}
```

and in you `struct` ScanView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingScanner = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingScanner = true
            }) {
                Text("Scan QR Code").foregroundColor(Color.white).padding()
            }.frame(width: 150)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(25)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingScanner) {
            ScannerView()
        }
    }
}
```

The camera view, I have dragged the camera view below so that you can see the button screen in the background:

[image]

P.S. Don't forget to add `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` in `info.plist`

Comment: This solution worked for presenting the view, the issue I'm facing with this fix now is that it pulls up the view but the camera view is blank? Picture reference here: https://imgur.com/a/gFw596A

Comment: I added that permission a while back, still nothing on the camera view. Could the issue be that the view that I'm attempting to pull up the view from is a nested view under contentview? I tried making an observable object and environment object to be able to pull the scanner up from the contentview but that code didn't work at all. I'm really confused what the issue is, I'm going to make a blank project and just use this code to see if the issue is based on the fact that the view is nested.

Comment: I just created a project with using just the code I've provided with the code you've provided as well, it works as intended. This leaves me with the mystery of why it doesn't work on my original project? I have the camera access added to the info.plist on the original project but it doesn't pull up a request to access camera like it does on the blank project?

Comment: For more context as I've tried more (unsuccessful) solutions to my issue; I use an observable object called viewRouter to navigate to separate subtrees of my views, as there are 5-6 different discrete navigation trees for different user types, the initial breakdown to the different trees is what occupies my contentview. I tried adding another branch specifically for the qr scanner, thinking maybe it had something to do with being nested outside of the contentview, but the same issue persists even with it being in the contentview directly. Is there anything I could provide to be more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an xCode expert. Much less a SwiftUI expert. But it looks like you're trying to navigate from a SwiftUI view to a UIKit view. That threw me off for a minute.

Anyways, you're going to want to wrap your button in a NavigationView.
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/216/complete-guide-to-navigationview-in-swiftui